# PDFTron giving the error while trying to load pdf using react

Tags: reactjs, pdf, pdftron

while using the WebViewer

```
    WebViewer({
      path: '/public',
      initialDoc: source,

    }, element);
```

like this gives error on console Uncaught in Promise

> type InvalidPDF Message Header not found

below is the actual error message

> Exception:     Message: PDF header not found. The file is not a valid
>   PDF document.
>       Filename:
>    Function: SkipHeader
>   Linenumber:

[Visited this link but content type is not xod it's pdf](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/faq/loading-errors/)

Comment: What version of WebViewer are you using? Also, can you double check in the browsers network panel that your server hosting the PDF file is indeed responding to the client with PDF data? It should start with "%PDF" in the binary.

Answer (score 0):

This is the PDFTron web team, and thank you for bringing this up!

Does this issue happen for every file you are loading, or is this a file specific issue? If it's file specific, could you please send us the document so that we can try to reproduce the issue on our end, and investigate it further.

If you'd like to keep the document private, you can submit a ticket via https://www.pdftron.com/form/request/.